# selecting last closing tag in xml search

Tags: xml, opencart-3, ocmod

I am using opencart V 3.0.3.7

I have a code structure in twig file like

```
<ul> // this is fixed
  <li>
   {% if somecondition %}
     <ul>
        <li>   </li>
     </ul> // Here <ul> </ul> is added dymanically...so number of <ul> </ul> tags is not fixed.
   {% endif %}
  </li>
</ul> // this  is fixed. want to search this tag in xml
```

I want to search last  in xml file

For first instance, works like

```
 <search index="0"><![CDATA[<ul>]]></search>
```

How to search **LAST**  ???

Answer (score 0):

You have four `<ul>` tags. And the last tag **index is 3**. So you can add in **XML** `index="3"` in the `search` tag.

And after which position you add this.

There is three-position:

You can add any position as per your code requirements.

```
position="(replace|before|after)"
```

##### Change Lines:

```
<search index="3" position="after"><![CDATA[<ul>]]></search>
```

##### Full Examples :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Select Last Closing Tag Example</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <author>Mujahid Bhoraniya | bhoraniyamujahid@gmail.com</author>
    <code>Mujahid Bhoraniya Coder</code>
    <link>http://www.opencart.com</link>
    <file path="">
        <operation>
            <search index="3" position="after"><![CDATA[<ul>]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Comment: It's useful or not? please reply here